# CSS grouping and subgrouping

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply style to all class X only if it's of class A, B or C without code duplication?

I understand grouping:

```
A, B, C {
   ...
}
```

But I want something like:

```
X, (A, B, C) {
   ...
}
```

How can I achieve this without duplicating code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you do this?

```
.X.A, .X.B, .X.C {
 /* rules */
}
```

That will match elements with both class X and A, or X and B, or X and C. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I was hoping for a shorter solution built into CSS. I know about this one, but is that the only way?

Comment: Yes. And this is built into CSS. =P

Comment: If you really need to mark something with that many classes, why don't you make a new class or that represents this union of classes?

Comment: Because those classes are a given - I'm using ExtJS and it has way too much predefined classes.

Comment: Ahh yes. I've used ExtJS extensively. There really is no way around dealing with the hugely absurd number of classes it uses. Trust me, I've tried. Just give in... =P

Comment: It's a really nice library - just styling it is rather... extensive as the library itself...

Comment: Yes definitely. I'd say I spent about the same amount of time customizing all the styles as I did actually writing the Javascript to make the widgets. You get used to all the extensive CSS. Lots of trial-and-error in there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I wanted to comment on Marc W's answer, but I guess I don't have enough reputation points to do so >=O

Please note that using multiple classes in a selector, like

```
.X.A, .X.B, .X.C {
 /* rules */
}
```

Isn't supported by IE6.

Comment: Good point. When I was doing Ext work a while back, we pretty much had to drop IE6 support in our product. Actually, that was a great bonus to using Ext in the first place. =)

Comment: @Kevin C.: Well, we should technically be murdering IE6 off whenever we get the chance anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I'm modifying BluePrintCSS to accommodate our needs. Not quite the same as what you're doing, but there is a need to constantly apply styles to bunches of classes or IDs at once just as you are doing.

I've found that it's quicker to built a 'generator' in Javascript and then use that to spit out all the repetitive CSS declarations via nested for loops and such.

The advantage is that when the framework is updated, I can make some tweaks to my script and quickly update my 'over-ride' styles.